# Elasticsearch warning - ignore_throttled parameter is deprecated

Tags: elasticsearch

We are getting spammed in our logs with tons of the following warnings:

```
2022-05-17 09:30:42 WARN  RestClient:65 - request [POST http://10.179.202.149:9201/categories/_search?typed_keys=true&ignore_unavailable=false&expand_wildcards=open&allow_no_indices=true&ignore_throttled=true&search_type=query_then_fetch&batched_reduce_size=512&ccs_minimize_roundtrips=true] returned 1 warnings: [299 Elasticsearch-7.17.1-e5acb99f822233d62d6444ce45a4543dc1c8059a "[ignore_throttled] parameter is deprecated because frozen indices have been deprecated. Consider cold or frozen tiers in place of frozen indices."]
```

All the threads online about this subject are not useful as they are indicating to just not to use "frozen indices", but we are not using them explicitly and just getting spammed with this warning.

We have not found a way to turn this warning off (RestClient is an internal Elasticsearch method), has anyone found an actual solution for this?

Elasticsearch: 7.17.1

Thanks

Comment: are you using Java High Level client or rest Client ?

Comment: Just change version of client to `7.17.2` and issue will be resolved. please let me know if this work for you.

Comment: @SagarPatel we are using the Java client, so the 7.17.2 version has this addressed?

Comment: Yes. I have posted answer. You can update version of dependancy in maven or gradle.

Comment: @SagarPatel great I will investigate, it will take a bit of time as we need to do a deployment, will reply at some point today once we do the release

Comment: Sure, You can test on local as well before deployment.

Comment: Could you check the solution, does it work?

Answer (score 4):

You can see [this](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/84827) PR and it is fixed in version `7.17.2`. So You need to update version of your Java client like below in maven;

```xml
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
     <artifactId>elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client</artifactId>
     <version>7.17.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I doubt that is useful, because after changing `elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client` version, I've got the following error: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/elasticsearch/xcontent/ToXContentObject`. Maybe `elastic` version is not suitable at all

Comment: Wait, I'm currently using High Level and Low level client at the same time, so when I just updated High Level Client Version it didn't work! But after updating Low Level and also Elasticsearch Version now everything works fine :)
`Elasticsearch: 7.17.2`, `High-Level-Client:7.17.2`, `Low-Level-Client:7.17.2`

Comment: This works, but only worked for me if my indexer code also used 7.17.2 and I needed to change absolutely every elasticsearch jar dependency in the pom.xml files. If I only changed a number of them it failed with exceptions.