# Fix Elasticsearch ignored_throttled warning

Tags: java, elasticsearch

Im using ES Version 8.6.2 and I keep getting this warning error

```
[299 Elasticsearch-8.6.2-e5acb99f822233d62d6444ce45a4543dc1c8059a "[ignore_throttled] parameter is deprecated because frozen indices have been deprecated. Consider cold or frozen tiers in place of frozen indices."]
```

Is there a way to fix this warning without downgrading Elasticsearch version.

Comment: Well there is a way indeed, either do not use frozen indices or do not send ignore_throttled parametter

Comment: [It has the answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72271872/elasticsearch-warning-ignore-throttled-parameter-is-deprecated)

Comment: @Paulo `ingore_throttled` is not the kind of parameter that you can control to send or not, the client sends the parameter to server. [You can see this](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/84827)

Comment: @Chenman but actually I think it would be appropriate by you to post more detailed question.

Answer (score 0):

1. You don't need to downgrade your `Elasticsearch` version, however you need to change the `Rest Client` version as following:

- Elasticsearch Rest High Level Client Maven Dependency:

  ```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
        <artifactId>elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client</artifactId>
        <version>7.17.2</version>
    </dependency>
  ```
- Elasticsearch Rest Low Level Client Maven Dependency:

  ```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
        <artifactId>elasticsearch-rest-client</artifactId>
        <version>7.17.2</version>
    </dependency>
  ```

2. As the source you can follow [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72271872/elasticsearch-warning-ignore-throttled-parameter-is-deprecated) which also discussed the same issue and there was reliable answer, which in fact I also checked in my case as well
3. And for more information you can also follow [this post](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/84827) which also discussed the main cause of the `ignore_throttled` deprecation in github discussion board.